# If a single alien landed on Earth with the intention of selling it from under us - how would they achieve this

Tags: aliens, invasion

My story revolves around the premise that an alien prospector discovered Earth at some point in the past armed with only one one weapons - longevity. Their intention is to mine the Earth and export it across the galaxy for sale to a galactic elite with more money than planets.

Now (in the 21st Century) we are in the middle of this process so I am interested to know what historic, current and future events would need to take place in order for this alien to manipulate us into building the infrastructure required to mine our own planet without realizing what is going on.

I imagine a combination of societal fragmentation through capitalism and the focus of the individual, inequality and the rise of the super elite concentrating power in the hands of a corruptible few and technology offering rich alternative realities to distract us from what is happening.

What I need are specific events, both real historical events and projected events based on current trends.

Assumptions:

1) It is only the top layers of the planet that are of interest - the organic layers that have value

2) The reason it is easier to mine a planet already inhabited is that this alien doesn't have the resources to build the infrastructure themselves

3) The manipulation is subtle and takes hundreds of years on a global scale. The aim of the alien is to find a way to make us do their bidding

4) I imagine the mining will be fully automated by the time it starts in a global scale and humans are largely not required

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Clay and welcome to worldbuilding. Sadly I decided to myself to flag your question as ***too broad***. This happened because as it stands any answer would not only need to make assumptions, but also would likely be very long. We currently do not have the equipment to mine planets (we can/have not even penetrated the outmost shell). So that would be the first thing to do. Then you need to bring humans to build this on the surface of earth (and not on the mars, where it would make much more sense, who wants to mine their own planet when there is one nearby?). ...

Comment: This cannot be answered unless you define what "ownership" means in this context.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, which one is the best/correctest/green-tick-worthiest? That is why I choosed to vote for closing. With a bit more limitations and a clearer "winning criterium" for answers I believe this can become a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Have added some assumptions to hopefully narrow the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

Take control of all the banking and finical institutions in the world and use the control of money to force nations to bend to your will.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icBp41jbuMo

Create a global economy based upon the extraction of these raw materials. (The industrial age).

Once maximum exploitation rates are reached use alien tech to make it all obsolete.

Swoop in with this off planet market for these goods to save the global economy and make a killing.

You will need an efficient way to transport the resources to make this viable. (I still think your premises is far fetched)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the premise would you say is far fetched out of interest? I never imagine any alien tech being used at all. Why isn't that plausible given current trends in globalisation, virtualisation etc?

Comment: There's only one slight issue: If you have alien tech that makes mining obsolete, why would the alien overlords be interested in mining the planet?

Comment: I never envisaged any tech that would make mining obsolete? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: The difficulty in transporting a whole planet, even piece by piece. There are more resources in this solar system alone in the form of comets, asteroids and moons then are held within the earth.  Energy is also an issue. Mathematically it takes far less energy to convert mater from a star then it does to transport an equal amount mater across space in a timely matter.

Comment: @Cyrus The aliens want the resources to make habitats. Earth used fossil fuels as an energy source. Aliens provide us with supper easy energy source. They then use our fossil fuel resources to make carbon nano tube structures to increase their living space.